# tabbarcontroller as a subview

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a main view screen with navcontroller in my app with two UIbuttons.
Now i want that when I press one button a subview will be pushed. this I know how to do.
The problem is that I want this subview to be with tabbarcontroller.
I know how to implement tabbar on the main views (within the app delegate), but I have really hard time to do this as a subview.. 
How should I implement this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't. It's been dealt with [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root-v) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208264/setting-a-tabbar-view-controller-as-a-sub-view-of-a-nav-controller) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482270/how-to-add-a-tabbar-to-navigationcontroller-based-iphone-app) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521500/tab-bar-within-a-navigation-based-aplication-again) that there is *no supported way* to have a tab bar controller as a subview of a navigation controller. Apple even says [in their documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW2) that the controller to push onto a navigation controller should not be a tab bar controller.