# How is the iPod app on the iPhone designed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

Is it just a tab-bar controller that loads some UITableViews that has navigation items set? Or is it a tab-bar controller that is loading a navigation controller?

Answer (score 3):

Tab-bar controller loading navigation controllers. That's the proper way to enable table drilling down to the content. If I recall properly you have to do this in code, IB can't nest these properly.

Comment: According to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830012 apparently nesting a nav controller inside of a tab-bar controller is not recommended?

Comment: @Sheehan that thread seems to say the opposite: you shouldn't put a tab-bar controller inside a nav controller.

Comment: I think you are reading that backwords. Apple doesn't want you putting a `UITabBarController` IN a `UINavigationController` however what I'm saying is to do the exact opposite. You have a `UITabBarController` and in some or all of the tabs you insert a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: You can actually do it in IB with the second view mode (tree view). See http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/